# Doute autre d'utiliser des adjectifs

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs

J'apprends les adjectifs en ce moment et j'ai un doute. Je sais qu'il y a des adjectifs qui se placent avant les noms. Souvent ils sont appellés "BAGS". Un adjectif qui appartient à de ce groupe est "belle" ou "beau". Alors, nous disons "une belle femme" et non "une femme belle". Dans ce cas-ci, le nom est "femme" et l'adjectif est "jolie". Cependant,dans cette expression :

> "La voiture est très belle."

Dans ce cas-ci, le nom est "la voiture" mais l'adjectif est après le nom. Pourquoi?

Comment: Pour ceux qui se demanderaient d'où sort ce « BAGS » : c'est un truc des profs de français pour public anglophone, BAGS → Beauty, Age, Goodness, Size, les adjectifs qui servent à décrire des qualités et qui se placent avant le nom.

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax Je ne pense pas que tous les profs de français pour anglophones font ça, c'est surtout un truc pour les débutants. Et ça ne peut marcher que pour des anglophones - ([bags](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pxUYJ6MnZqk&nohtml5=False) 40s). On dit souvent que les adjectifs « courant courts » se placent avant le nom [par exemple](http://www.bertrandboutin.ca/Folder_151_Grammaire/F_f_place_adj.htm#_adjectifs_courants_courts). Un natif n'aurait pas besoin de cette règle, il place l'adjectif par l'usage, et c'est de toute façon beaucoup plus complexe que ce BAGS.

Answer (score 4):

L'adjectif qualificatif a deux fonctions :

L'adjectif épithète.
L'adjectif est épithète lorsqu'il qualifie le nom ; il le suit ou le précède et s'accorde alors en genre et en nombre avec lui
Exemple : La belle femme est au restaurant.

L'adjectif attribut
L'adjectif est attribut du sujet (il appartient au sujet) quand il y a un verbe d'état placé devant lui ; l'adjectif s'accorde alors en genre et en nombre avec ce sujet. Les verbes d'état sont : être - sembler - paraître - devenir -  avoir l'air - rester - demeurer , et leurs synonymes
Exemple : La femme est belle.

Donc les adjectifs du groupe que vous appelez "BAGS", sont toujours placés devant le nom **s'ils ont une valeur épithète**.

Comment: Il me semble que tous ces adjectifs peuvent etre utilisés en epithete.

Comment: Notez qu'il y a des cas qui peuvent piéger le débutant, par exemple si je dis "Je sors rassasié du restaurant", "rassasié" est un épithète (détaché) car "sors" n'est pas un verbe d'état ("sors" n'explique pas le lien entre "je" et "rassasié").