# Les adjectifs qui ont deux sens

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, adjectifs

J’ai appris que certains mots comme « curieux », « grand », « propre », « sale » etc.  ont 2 sens selon leur place avant ou après le nom.

Souvent, ils ont leur sens littéral lorsque placés derrière le nom.

- Il a un caractère sale. (il n’est pas propre)
- Il a un sale caractère. (il n’est pas sociable/gentil)

Je crois qu’il y en a beaucoup que je ne connais pas encore ; donc pourriez-vous me donner le site qui peut m’expliquer, s’il vous plaît ?

Comment: *Il a un caractère sale* n'est pas vraiment idiomatique et laissera perplexe beaucoup d'entre nous. Ce n'est pas le meilleur exemple que l'on peut trouver pour illustrer la question. Je te suggère ***il a un chien sale*** et ***il a un sale chien***.

Comment: Y a-t-il systématiquement locution nominale quand il y a antéposition ? Est-ce l'absence ou la présence d'une locution nominale qui explique l'observation antéposition/postposition : en d'autres termes ce classement est-il utile ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quand peut-on mettre un adjectif avant ou après un nom ? — When do adjectives go before or after a noun?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/319/quand-peut-on-mettre-un-adjectif-avant-ou-apr%c3%a8s-un-nom-when-do-adjectives-go)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a list of several adjectives which have a different sense according to whether they are placed before or after the noun. It's not a complete one.

> ancien, brave, certain, cher, dernier, différent, grand, nouveau,
>   pauvre, prochain, propre, seul, vrai

Cf.

```
Un ancien élève vs une maison ancienne.

Mon cher ami vs un repas cher

Un grand homme un homme grand

Un nouvel effort vs un procédé nouveau

Sa propre maison vs une maison propre

Un seul candidat vs la force seule ne suffira pas

Un vrai ami vs une histoire vraie
```

etc.

Voir

https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Cat%C3%A9gorie:Adjectifs_en_fran%C3%A7ais_qui_changent_de_sens_avec_la_position

http://monsu.desiderio.free.fr/atelier/adjsens.html

Comment: I find most of these examples very poorly chosen, but the links are relevant.

Comment: @LaurentS. I mostly found them in a grammar book (https://www.amazon.co.uk/French-Reference-Grammar-H-Ferrar/dp/0199120331/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=A+French+Reference+Grammar+by+H.+Ferrar&qid=1580205687&sr=8-1)

Comment: Still... the first one doesn't even change the order (thus the meaning), "nouvel effort vs procédé nouveau" doesn't make any sense, the example with "seul" isn't that obvious,...

Comment: Pourquoi employer des substantifs différents ? Pourquoi pas « une ancienne maison », « une maison ancienne » etc.

Answer (score 1):

Il n'y a probablement pas de référence standard ni de site sur ce sujet. La meilleure source d'information est encore le FSE (pour un début), mais ce que vous recherchez représente un travail volumineux. Commencez par consulter les titres FSE sur l'adjectif. Dans la zone de texte « Search on French Language » tapez « title:adjectif » puis « entrée » ; cela donne accès à 36 résultats ; recommencez avec « adjective » à la place de « adjectif », (68 de plus). Parmi ces questions et réponses vous trouverez des liens qui peuvent vous apprendre quelque chose.

Une recherche telle qu'indiquée ci-dessus, mais rapide, résulte en les questions les plus productives ; leur url sont collectées ci-dessous.

[Quand peut-on mettre un adjectif avant ou après un nom ? — When do adjectives go before or after a noun?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/319/17649)

[Adjective position with "quelque chose"](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/23720/17649)

[Position of the adjective in complex sentences](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/29065/17649)

[How to understand double-meaning adjective placement](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/22747/17649)

[Adjective before/after noun when preceded by quantifier](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/23437/17649)

[How can I find the meaning of an adjective that comes before the noun?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/27852/17649)

Here is a supplement of questions that treat the subject and that should be checked to verify whether they contain what is needed.

[La place des adjectifs qualificatifs](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/29168/17649)

[Doute autre d'utiliser des adjectifs](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/18510/17649)

[Comment se rappeler des sens divers de certains adjectifs ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/8613/17649)

[Quand doit-on placer les adjectifs de taille devant des noms ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/4619/17649)

[Same adjectives, different meanings used together in same sentence](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/27716/17649)

[Is there a general guide on how adjectives change meaning with position?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/21599/17649)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103760/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-les-adjectifs-qui-ont-deux-sens).